# Google tabs IMPORTRANGE with SUMIF problems

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, sumifs

I know it has already been a few times discussed topic, but I haven't found any help that would suit my problem yet.
I'm trying to make a sum of numbers in one column in a different Google sheet. The problem is I need to sum only those numbers happened in chosen month. I have the number of the month in the sheet where I need the function, and I have the month specifikation in a column next to the numbers.

All I came to till now is this (after many totally different codes):

```
=sum(query(IMPORTRANGE("xyz";"Výkaz!B23:C125");"select Col2,Col3 where "col2=G4";0)"))
```

- G4 is the chosen month I have in the same sheet as this code

Please, could you help me figure this out? Thank you

Comment: Please share a sample sheet with data. Easier to fix bugs if one can see the sheet and data.

Comment: The sheets you share are not available without requesting for authorization. Could you share them publicly or make a copy with similar data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Sheet 1 (TabName = "externalTab")

Google Sheet 2 (TabName = "InternalTab")

Use importrange to pull the all data from "externalTab" to "Internal Tab". Then just use a sumifs formula to add up values based on your criteria.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sLPGZkAVlxWfjhDMU9oa_cww0AI570Rtem0XCoOx0AE", "'externalTab '!A1:AF2000")
```

Alternatively use the following formula. Integers to be summed are located in column a/Col1 and Months are located in column b/Col2. There is one header row on the spreadsheet and we are adding up all the Integers that correspond to the month June.

```
=sum(query(importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sLPGZkAVlxWfjhDMU9oa_cww0AI570Rtem0XCoOx0AE","a1:b1000"),"select Col1, Col2 WHERE Col2 = 'June'",1))
```

Comment: Thank you. I know about this possibility, only I don't want tha same data in the second "internal" sheet. That's why I'm trying to figure out some code.

Comment: Why don't you want the same data in the second "internal" sheet ?

Comment: Because we want each sheet to be shared with different colleagues and in the Internal one are supposed to be data from more than just one external sheet. I'm trying to avoind having the data in the internal sheet because that's actually why I made it :/ I would like it to be as simple as it could be

Comment: It's a lot easier to work with the data in you have it all inside the one Google Sheet. If I were you I would create a separate tab for each external sheet, then import the data the data for the external sheets into separate tabs. Then create a master tab and run whatever formula you want from there. Just protect and hide the other tabs and you will be left with a master tab that you can use internally. It is also a lot more each to fault find when all the data is in one google spread sheet.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I understand that. Unfortunately we have like 60 of these external sheets from which we need to get just some total data info another like 15 sheets. It would be just really helpful it the code worked somehow, but I understand it's a lot complicated for the google sheets :/

Comment: I updated my answer above to include alternative method that will achieve what you want

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help! Together with it and some other info I found on the internet I finally found the right code:
=query( importrange("..."; "Výkaz!A23:C125"); "select sum(Col3) where Col2 = '" & trim(G4) & "' "; 0 )